# How to clear inactive memory in Android programmatically?

Tags: android, memory, memory-management

How to free inactive memory in Android? I have seen some applications that claim to free RAM programmatically. After having studied them I found they free inactive memory of the device. Are there any APIs to do this?

Comment: this is not working.I have seen an application clean master that claim immediately free memory when we free the memory and  programmatically i checked the same and found it is not fake. any help?

Answer (score 23):

check this [link](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/04/24/explicitly-free-memory-android-release-unwanted-memory-android/)

main code from it :

```
public void freeMemory(){       
    System.runFinalization();
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
    System.gc();
}
```

Comment: in which method we can use this function

Answer (score 6):

call the garbage collector to free memory , best place to call it is onDestroy()

eg :

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    System.gc();

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: What is the point of this ? If you're destroying yourself, isn't the memory freed anyway ?